# Problem when doing apt update to prepare my ubuntu in order to install cacti

Tags: apt, updates

I need help please since i am getting the following error while doing sudo apt update:

```
root@template:~# sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:2 http://fr.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not connect to fr.archive.canonical.com:80 (185.125.189.10), connection timed out
Err:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Err:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
0% [Waiting for headers]
```

In addition, i am well connected to the internet
Please if someone can help debugging this issue.
Thank you

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. A test connection to that mirror works for me. Try again.